# Trying to start MongoDB and failing

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to start MongoDB and I am getting an error.

Here is my `connection.js` in my backend:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Get the port number from an environmental variable
const port = process.env.MONGODB_PORT || 27017;

const connectionString = `mongodb://localhost:${port}/ChainedWolfeMetalCrafts`;

mongoose.connect(connectionString, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Where do you "start mongodb" in the given code? Also, how is this problem related to [tag:localhost] or [tag:backend]?

Comment: The code you show is trying to _connect to_ MongoDB, not start it. If it's not already started and listening on 27017: there's your problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how do i start it?

Comment: @NicoHaase THis is my first time asking a question. I am new to developing. Sorry.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/installation/

Comment: Is your `mongod` running?